# How to make thread 2,3 and 4 wait for same signal from thread1?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a function to be executed by thread1,2,3,4.... Once thread1 gets access to the function, I use thread_cond for waiting for the other threads. Once thread1 does its work, I send thread_signal to the same cond. Thread2 is executing the function. But after it finishes execution, the other threads don't get access to the function.

Please help me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int limit = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex[100];
pthread_cond_t cond[100];
pthread_t tid[100];

void *enter()
{
    if (limit == 1)
    {
        printf("waiting\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond[1],&mutex[1]);
    }
    gotofunction();
}

void gotofunction()
{
    limit++;
    /* Do work */
    printf("Doing work\n");
    sleep(1);
    limit--;
    printf("Going to give signal\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex[i], NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&cond[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, enter, NULL);
        sleep(0.5);
    }
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

Basically thread1 prints "doing work"
Thread2 prints "doing work"
Then nothing happens for the other threads

Comment: The `pthread_cond_signal` only signals *one* (random) thread. If you read the manual page for e.g. `pthread_cond_signal`, it doesn't tell you about some other function? Perhaps one to [*broadcast*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) the signal?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think broadcast wakes all the threads up. I want only one of the thread to wakeup and do its work then wake one more thread and so on

Comment: Then perhaps a *chain* of `pthread_cond_signal`? Once a thread wakes up after a signal, it in turn call `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, am I not doing the same thing? thread1 executes gotofunction() and then wakes up one of the threads, that thread executes gotofunction and in turn wake up another thread and so on...

Comment: I think it's time you do something you should have done from the start (and we should have asked for earlier): To create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please check the above complete code. When I execute with some n say 7. The program only outputs "Doing Work" and "Going to give signal"  only twice (whereas it should be executed by each n threads).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude did I provide you with details you expected?

Comment: Yes that's perfect. There are a few things that seems "off". Like you not joining all threads (and attempt to join a non-existing thread). Like the possible race conditions in the threads, when you don't protect the shared `limit` variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you explain me on joining all threads part, didn't quite get you there. What is the non-existing thread. I basically wanted to wait for all the threads to finish executed before the program terminates. Any other alternative?

Comment: Semaphores seem perfect for this.  See [`sem_post()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_post.html) and [`sem_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_wait.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am constrained to only use pthread_wait, cond. Any help?

Comment: @user7693981  First, you need to solve how a thread can tell if it's thread #1, or thread #2, etc.  And no, don't pass `&i` in the `for` loop to the thread...

Comment: Take a look at the loop calling `pthread_join`. The `for` should be a copy-paste of the `for` when you create the threads. Since the join-loop goes from `1` to `n` (*inclusive*) you will not join the first thread you create, and you will attempt to call `pthread_join` with `tid[n]` which is zero-initialized.

Comment: OT: `void *enter()` misses to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the mutex that you passed to `pthread_cond_wait()` locked at the time you call it.  That mutex must also be locked while you check and change the condition that the condition variable is paired with (in this case, `limit == 1` is that condition).

You should also use the pattern `while (condition) { pthread_cond_wait() }` (rather than `if (condition)`), because the condition variable may wake up without the condition actually being true.

Changing your code to lock the mutex around the accesses to `limit`, and unlock it while simulating the work, looks like this:

```
void *enter()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[1]);
    while (limit == 1)
    {
        printf("waiting\n");
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond[1],&mutex[1]);
    }
    gotofunction();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[1]);
    return NULL;
}

void gotofunction()
{
    limit++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[1]);

    /* Do work */
    printf("Doing work\n");
    sleep(1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[1]);
    limit--;
    printf("Going to give signal\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond[1]);
}
```

Of course when you check against a limit of 1, you could just use a plain mutex instead - but this scheme could be extended to allow N threads to execute work simultaneously, by changing the condition to `while (limit >= N)`.